# Какие есть способы получения currentState или вызова setState виджетов в ListView? (желательно по их индексу)

Tags: flutter

###### Описание ситуации:

Возьмем общую (распространенную, частую) ситуацию в которой через `ListView.builder` динамически строится список stateful виджетов.
Для простоты представим что у каждого виджета в списке может быть одно из двух состояний по булевому свойству, текущее состояние меняется с анимацией (внутренняя реализация в виджетах через их локальный State), и что позиции виджетов в списке постоянны.
Предполагается анимированное изменение состояний сразу нескольких виджетов в списке по некоторому "внешнему" событию (неважно по какому, допустим по нажатию кнопки в AppBar).

###### Проблема:

Если для переключения состояния виджетов в списке мы используем параметр их конструктора, то тем самым будем перестраивать их - и анимация перехода между состояниями не будет выполняться (т.к. виджеты при этом просто заменяются новыми).
Найдя/добавив в классе стейта таких виджетов метод для программного изменения состояния, условно `toggle(newStateValue)`, сталкиваемся с проблемой - непонятно как этот метод вызвать для виджета в определенной позиции в списке, при том что виджеты в `ListView` создаются builder-функцией, а у листвью нет свойства/метода вида "childByIndex".

##### Суть вопроса:

Как можно менять локальный State / вызывать методы стейта некоторых stateful виджетов в `ListView` зная их индексы? То есть, менять состояние виджетов без их перестраивания с потерей анимированного перехода
*// Проблема тут **не** в написании кода. Суть проблемы именно в том, что когда список строится динамически (вместо декларативного описания каждого его элемента) - неясно как вообще можно получить объект State виджета в `ListView`, зная позицию виджета в списке. Другими словами, неясен путь решения подобных задач (общая логика решения).*

<sub>**Рассуждения на данный момент:**

Можно процедурно строить `List` виджетов и затем передавать его в `ListView`, но тогда теряется целый ряд плюшек реактивного перестраивания дерева виджетов и декларативность (такое решение противоречит flutter-way).

Еще есть идея использовать `GlobalKey` в виджетах внутри списка (запоминая ключи в List'e), но думаю что так получится утечка памяти - то есть, объекты State не смогут нормально разрушаться из-за ссылок на них. Плюс, глобальные ключи это как глобальные переменные (в случае локального списка, это явно оверкилл).</sub>

Comment: Можете привести минимальный работоспособный пример кода? Сложно понять с чем проблема и как ее можно решить, читая только текст...

Comment: @MiT, код добавить не смогу в ближайшие дни. И даже если бы мог, то не стал бы, т.к. этот вопрос задан совсем не о коде: суть вопроса изложена под словосочетанием "суть вопроса", выделенным жирным шрифтом (а для понимания проблемы, рекомендую прочесть текст под словом "проблема", которое так же выделено жирным). То есть, вместо ответа на какой-либо код, тут хотелось бы увидеть ответы именно на заданный вопрос.

Comment: Решение _возможно_ найдено (спасибо гениальности Rémi Rousselet) - если оно сработает, напишу ответом через пару дней (раньше проверить у меня не получится). Спойлер: суть идеи в пробросе `StreamController`'a для двусторонней связи, не мешающий работе механизмов перестроения/освобождения виджетов.

Comment: что-то вроде EventBus?

Comment: @MiT, да, типа шины событий со вкусом Rx. Вроде можно использовать единый общий стрим для сообщений в обе стороны (родитель <--> дочерние) - если так, то будет весьма удобно, и останется только найти способ сделать переиспользуемую обертку: чтобы ее точечно использовать только там где необходимо (и при этом каждый класс виджета не наследовать отдельно). Общая идея ведь в том чтобы в стейте родителя держать общий стрим, а значит дочерним виджетам надо как-то передавать его... можно конечно пойти самым легким путем, обертку сделав просто виджетом, но хочется покрасивее-посахарнее придумать :)

Comment: И еще provider есть (вариант инжектить зависимость), и все-таки мне кажется что такое можно реализовать вообще без каких-либо доп. пакетов, чистым дартовым ООП. Уже не терпится попробовать порешать :) как новичку, мне такие задачи кажутся крайне интересными, хоть они и ограниченно применимы на практике.

Comment: День добрый, есть решение проблемы?

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем уверен чего вы хотите добиться. Старайтесь управлять состоянием дочерних виджетов в родительском виджете, особенно в listview. Состояния всех элементов будут под контролем.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  List<bool> items = [
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            items[1] = true;
            items[3] = true;
          });
        },
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return Item(
            selected: items[index],
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                items[index] = !items[index];
              });
            },
          );
        },
        itemCount: items.length,
      )
    );
  }
}



class Item extends StatelessWidget{

  final VoidCallback onTap;

  final bool selected;

  const Item({Key key, this.onTap, this.selected}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => onTap(),
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 40,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
        color: selected ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: "Подъем" состояния в родительский виджет - в некоторых ситуациях действительно может быть решением, но в других ситуациях такое является таким же страшным антипаттерном как хардкод индексов/длины динамических структур. И конечно же, это никоим образом не отвечает на заданный вопрос о доступе к стейту дочернего виджета созданного builder-функцией...